# Change the orientation of UIImage in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, orientation

Can any body tell me that how can i set the Orientation of my UIImage. That is if my UIImage orientation is **UIImageOrientationDown** then i Want to change it to **UIImageOrientationUp**.

Can anybody please tell me how can I achieve this.

I have searched a lot but up till now i have found only regarding how to get the image orientation.

Answer (score 0):

try :-

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {        
        yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2);
    }
    else {
        yourImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the UIIMage delegate ?

Comment: @sHaH.. Nup.... UIViewController 's ...It will detect the orientation change event

Comment: ah... Not helpfull brother. :(

Comment: @sHaH..: How you want to change the orientation of image ? I mean when you change the device's orientation or on button click ?

Comment: The orientation of my app is always Left Or RIght. but when i open camera. Its Orientation is left,right,up, down. all of that. So when i take picture in down mode it should rotate it to up mode automatically and if i take picture in left mode it should roatate it to Right Mode. so that my picture comes up in Perfect Orientation. Hope you get my point